# OrientDB Lucene "within" bounding box search

Tags: lucene, geospatial, orientdb

I was using OrientDB Lucene Spatial Index on my DB, was looking to use bounding box search, but I was wondering how does `within` parameter works?

Eg from Lucene OrientDB
`select * from Places where [latitude,longitude] WITHIN [[51.507222,-0.1275],[55.507222,-0.1275]]`

How does it compute bounding box within this 2 latlng parameters? when they have the same longitude.

Please advice, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking into their code, I found that they are building the bounding box [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-lucene/blob/12a39c318203ae7977992ed50fd25c7cc615c659/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/lucene/shape/ORectangleShapeFactory.java#L42). Where they are only taking 2 latlng parameters to build the bounding box, which is `SouthWest`(1st param) and `NorthEast` (2nd Param).
They are using [Spatial4j](https://github.com/spatial4j/spatial4j) Library as their geospatial library.